# making text adaptive with screen size in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-responsive-layout

I was developing a simple basketball points counter app using flutter, but I have an error
this is the initial UI of the app

[image: this is the initial UI of the app]

when the number of digits inside the Text widget increase, an overflow happens like what happen in this photo

[image: when the digits in text widget increase, an overflow happens]

and also this photo

[image: overflow]

so how can I handle this issue to prevent overflow, I tried some solutions but the issue still happening.

this is my screen size :
Height is 781.1 and width is 392.7 –

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int numOfPointsTeamA = 0;
  int numOfPointsTeamB = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        title: const Text(
          'Basketball Points Counter',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 468,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Team A',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$numOfPointsTeamA',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 200, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamA++;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 1 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamA += 2;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 2 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamA += 3;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 3 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  const VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    thickness: 0.5,
                    width: 70,
                  ),
                  Column(children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Team B',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$numOfPointsTeamB',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 200, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamB++;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 1 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamB += 2;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 2 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamB += 3;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 3 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    numOfPointsTeamA = 0;
                    numOfPointsTeamB = 0;
                  });
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                child: const Text(
                  'Reset',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you determine what is your device `width` and `height`?

Comment: Height is **781.1** and width is **392.7**

Comment: You can refer this [code](https://github.com/DabPb/BBall-score-App) for better experience,

Happy Codding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package as doc

```
AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

in your case wrap your `Column` with `Flexible` and the text too:

```
Flexible(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            Flexible(
                child: AutoSizeText(
                    '$numOfPointsTeamB',
                    maxFontSize: 150, // set max and min to handle
                    minFontSize: 100,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
            ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

you can use `overflow: TextOverflow.fade` but i dont think its good for you, and i think you need a logic to check if the number is too long, change fontsize or dont let to be bigger than 2000 for example.

[image: result]

Comment: I've tried it but the issue still appears

Answer (score 1):

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int numOfPointsTeamA = 0;
  int numOfPointsTeamB = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        title: const Text(
          'Basketball Points Counter',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 468,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(children: [
                    RichText(     //<----- here replace it with the Text Widget 
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$numOfPointsTeamA',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 200, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamA++;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 1 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamA += 2;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 2 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamA += 3;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 3 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                  const VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    thickness: 0.5,
                    width: 70,
                  ),
                  Column(children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Team B',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$numOfPointsTeamB',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 200, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamB++;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 1 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamB += 2;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 2 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 7,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          numOfPointsTeamB += 3;
                        });
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                      child: const Text(
                        'Add 3 point',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    numOfPointsTeamA = 0;
                    numOfPointsTeamB = 0;
                  });
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.orange),
                child: const Text(
                  'Reset',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 25,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code do? , why did you use TextSpan

Answer (score 0):

try this and adjust it as u want

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: I don't understand you, where should I try this ?

Comment: i post it using ur on code